# The refresh rate is terrible. How does PyQt5's Matplotlib add to FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt

### EXPLANATION

I added a Gif to indicate the refresh condition and refreshed every 100 milliseconds. I couldn't improve the refresh rate because the 100 milliseconds fit program had become slow and sluggish. So I tried using FuncAnimation, but the program seemed to go wrong.

[image: Gif Picture showing the problem]

### ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 287, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 909, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1698, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(frame_data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1720, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

### Code:

```py
...
class Figure_Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=3, height=2, dpi=70):
        E1 = [[0.63761403,0.89417356,0.39254607,0.37453972,0.82157584,0.9758471
 ,0.98862653,0.39789754,0.90103551,0.9070236 ,0.1695829 ,0.43161161
 ,0.94370207,0.35554033,0.49323543,0.86870854],
 [0.90529073,0.40187087,0.91937448,0.12596673,0.020976  ,0.43221631
 ,0.87376804,0.4742405 ,0.72241299,0.50383465,0.75832025,0.1409374
 ,0.58894898,0.05888731,0.31792719,0.61323999]
        ...... 
        ]

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 50000, num=50000)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

    def updatePlot(self):
        if((self.index+50000)<2292526):
            self.axes.cla() 
            self.axes.set_ylim(-500.0, 500.0)
            self.axes.set_xlim(0.0, 50000.0)
            self.axes.plot(self.x, self[self.index:50000 + self.index] * 500000)
            self.index += 300
            self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
...
class UiForm(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.plot = False
        self.dr = Figure_Canvas(width=5, height=1.9)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(550, 419)
        ......
        self.dr.updatePlot()
        self.graphicscene.addWidget(self.dr)
        self.graphicview.setScene(self.graphicscene)
        self.graphicview.show()

        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(100)
...
```

#### Code Part Change:

```py
    def updatePlot(self):
        if((self.index+50000)<2292526):
            self.axes.cla()
            self.axes.plot(self.x, self[self.index:50000 + self.index] * 500000)
            self.index += 300
            self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
```

**Change to**

```py
    def updatePlot(self):
        def upgrade():
            self.axes.cla()
            self.plot_line, = self.axes.plot([], [], 'r-')

            x_data = []
            y_data = []
            for i in range(2292526):
                x_data.append(i)
                y_data.append(self.E1_emg[i])
            self.axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'r-')
        ani=FuncAnimation(self.fig,upgrade(),blit=True,repeat=True)
        self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
```

#### More Code:

https://gist.github.com/allrobot/7b668a3297ee3fdf2c1a4f1b59c84ee2

#### E1 data:

E1_emg.shape=[2292526,16]

### Question

Please tell me where the error part is and how to change it to make the output smooth?

Comment: `width` and `height` are attributes of all QWidgets (from which FigureCanvas inherits from), so you should not overwrite them. Change both to something else, like `self._width` and `self._height`.

Comment: @muscicamante Changed, but FuncAnimation could not refresh dynamically. May be 2292526 is too large, how to achieve 120 FPS high speed refresh?

Comment: I don't know. You added a lot of code, but no [mre], so it's really hard to understand where the problem is. In any case, don't put just random arbitrary numbers hoping that they work, try some basic debugging by printing values to understand if functions are called and with what parameters.

Comment: You seem to update a lot of things. Try `axes.redraw_in_frame()` instead of `canvas.draw()` in your original code. Forget animations completely if you are attempting to produce a live plot for an UI and not a pre-rendered animation.

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, I try to do attempting to produce a live plot for an UI. Now I'll try `axes.redraw_in_frame()`.